# What causes the error in the case of using let?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

```
interface Incrementor {
  (x: number): number;
  increment: number;
}

const a: Incrementor = function (x) { return 111 };
a.increment = 111;

let a1: Incrementor = function (x) { return 111 };
a1.increment = 111;
```

In the case of using *let*,the error tip shows "Property 'increment' is missing in type '(x: number) => number' but required in type 'Incrementor'".
However **it dosn't show** in the case of using *const*.

What's the difference between using ***let*** and ***const*** in this example？

Here's the original code:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIgVCBbC4D2UyA3gFDLIAUAHgFzIgCu2ARtAJT1OvQDc5yUJhx4wXZmyj8AvqVIJ8IAM5hkceumG4CRALzIYjDGGCKq1diWRYwjKCGQBGZ8mn84AOiFZtq-c8d+UgAbCFU4Rw0MH1FCZH1DY1MHGktiazC7BwDXd0cvaJFweKdnXiA

Comment: If U use `[index: string]: any` instead of `increment: number` it will work, but it will be still cheating. But if you change it to `[index: string]: number` it will throw error

Comment: @SerhiiBilyk Of course,[index: string]: any allows empty key-value

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with let and const, boo and foo both should show errors coz you are initializing them with function not Incrementor.

```
const boo: Incrementor = function (x) { return 111 }; // <- Error
let foo: Incrementor = function (x) { return 111 }; // <- Error
```

Comment: Both boo and foo here should be initialized with function coz the interface Incrementor describes a function type.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a bug and I don't know what Typescript has done to *const* variable.And I find a way to correct the error in this example:`let a1: Incrementor = function(x) { return 11 } as Incrementor;`